# Documentation for the API exposed from Pressflow

Tags: 6

Reading [How do Pressflow Drupal sites handle user Cookies?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/how-do-pressflow-drupal-sites-handle-user-cookies) I discovered that Pressflow 6 has a function that is not present in Drupal 6, but that is defined in Drupal 7; although, the code used by Pressflow 6 is different from the code used by the homonym function in Drupal 7.

Should developers use only the functions that are defined from the equivalent Drupal version (e.g. Drupal 6 for Pressflow 6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressflow is designed to be API compatible with Drupal. As a consequence you should only use the API functions of Drupal 6 when developing for Pressflow 6.